# How can I use scipy.ndimage.interpolation.affine_transform to rotate an image about its centre?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, rotation, scipy

I am perplexed by the API to [`scipy.ndimage.interpolation.affine_transform`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.affine_transform.html).  And judging by [this issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2255) I'm not the only one.  I'm actually wanting to do more interesting things with `affine_transform` than just rotating an image, but a rotation would do for starters.  (And yes I'm well aware of [`scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate.html), but figuring out how to drive `affine_transform` is what interests me here).

When I want to do this sort of thing in systems like OpenGL, I'm think in terms of computing the transform which applies a 2x2 rotation matrix `R` about a centre `c`, and therefore thinking of points `p` being transformed `(p-c)R+c` = `pR+c-cR`, which gives a `c-cR` term to be used as the translation component of a transform.  **However**, according to the issue above, scipy's `affine_transform` does "*offset first*" so we actually need to compute an offset `s` such that `(p-c)R+c=(p+s)R` which with a bit of rearrangement gives `s=(c-cR)R'` where `R'` is the inverse of `R`.

If I plug this into an ipython notebook (pylab mode; code below maybe needs some additional imports):

```
img=scipy.misc.lena()
#imshow(img,cmap=cm.gray);show()
centre=0.5*array(img.shape)
a=15.0*pi/180.0
rot=array([[cos(a),sin(a)],[-sin(a),cos(a)]])
offset=(centre-centre.dot(rot)).dot(linalg.inv(rot))
rotimg=scipy.ndimage.interpolation.affine_transform(
    img,rot,order=2,offset=offset,cval=0.0,output=float32
)
imshow(rotimg,cmap=cm.gray);show()
```

I get

[image: rotated but not about centre lena image]

which unfortunately isn't rotated about the centre.

So what's the trick I'm missing here?

Comment: Just doing some quick & dirty testing I noticed that taking the negative value of your offset seems to rotate about the centre.

Comment: Aha!  Yes, excellent, confirmed here.  It seems my model of scipy's system should be `(p-s)R`.  Put that as an answer and I'd accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just doing some quick & dirty testing I noticed that taking the negative value of your offset seems to rotate about the centre.

Answer (score 19):

Once treddy's answer got me a working baseline, I managed to get a better working model of `affine_transform`.  It's not actually as odd as the issue linked in the original question hints.

Basically, each point (coordinate) `p` in the output image is transformed to `pT+s` where `T` and `s` are the matrix and offset passed to the function.
So if we want point `c_out` in the output to be mapped to and sampled from `c_in` from the input image, with rotation `R` and (possibly anisotropic) scaling `S` we need `pT+s = (p-c_out)RS+c_in` which can be rearranged to yield `s = (c_int-c_out)T` (with `T=RS`).

For some reason I then need to pass `transform.T` to `affine_transform` but I'm not going to worry about that too much; probably something to do with row-coordinates with transforms on the right (assumed above) vs column-coordinates with transforms on the left.

So here's a simple test rotating a centred image:

```
src=scipy.misc.lena()
c_in=0.5*array(src.shape)
c_out=array((256.0,256.0))
for i in xrange(0,7):
    a=i*15.0*pi/180.0
    transform=array([[cos(a),-sin(a)],[sin(a),cos(a)]])
    offset=c_in-c_out.dot(transform)
    dst=scipy.ndimage.interpolation.affine_transform(
        src,transform.T,order=2,offset=offset,output_shape=(512,512),cval=0.0,output=float32
    )
    subplot(1,7,i+1);axis('off');imshow(dst,cmap=cm.gray)
show()
```

[image: Spinning Lena]

Here's it modified for different image sizes

```
src=scipy.misc.lena()[::2,::2]
c_in=0.5*array(src.shape)
c_out=array((256.0,256.0))
for i in xrange(0,7):
    a=i*15.0*pi/180.0
    transform=array([[cos(a),-sin(a)],[sin(a),cos(a)]])
    offset=c_in-c_out.dot(transform)
    dst=scipy.ndimage.interpolation.affine_transform(
        src,transform.T,order=2,offset=offset,output_shape=(512,512),cval=0.0,output=float32
    )
    subplot(1,7,i+1);axis('off');imshow(dst,cmap=cm.gray)
show()
```

[image: Spinning small Lena]

And here's a version with anisotropic scaling to compensate for the anisotropic resolution of the source image.

```
src=scipy.misc.lena()[::2,::4]
c_in=0.5*array(src.shape)
c_out=array((256.0,256.0))
for i in xrange(0,7):
    a=i*15.0*pi/180.0
    transform=array([[cos(a),-sin(a)],[sin(a),cos(a)]]).dot(diag(([0.5,0.25])))
    offset=c_in-c_out.dot(transform)
    dst=scipy.ndimage.interpolation.affine_transform(
        src,transform.T,order=2,offset=offset,output_shape=(512,512),cval=0.0,output=float32
    )
    subplot(1,7,i+1);axis('off');imshow(dst,cmap=cm.gray)
show()
```

[image: Spinning anisotropic Lena]

Comment: awesome, how could i have it rotate and fill the screen? (rotate without leaving any black/transparent space at the corners?

Comment: You'd have to incorporate a sufficiently high zoom factor about the centre of the image into the transform; for a square image in a square window a factor of sqrt(2) would do it.

Comment: Anyone coming to this in 2016+ note that there seems to have been a recent scipy bugfix  which may or may not change some details of the above; see https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2255 and https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/5794

Comment: @FightFireWithFire You a Metallica fan? :-)

Answer (score 12):

Based on the insight from @timday that `matrix` and `offset` are defined in the output coordinate system, I would offer the following reading of the issue, which fits with standard notations in linear algebra and allows to understand the scaling of images as well. I use here `T.inv=T^-1` as pseudo-python notation to mean the inverse of a matrix and `*` to mean the dot product.

For each point `o` in the output image, `affine_transform` finds the corresponding point `i` in the input image as `i=T.inv*o+s`, where `matrix=T.inv` is the *inverse* of the 2x2 transformation matrix that one would use to define the forward affine transformation and `offset=s` is the translation defined in the output coordinates. For a pure rotation `T=R=[[cos,-sin],[sin,cos]]`, and in this special case `matrix=T.inv=T.T`, which is the reason why @timday had to apply the transposition still (alternatively one could just use the negative angle).

The value for the offset `s` is found exactly the way described by @timday: if `c_in` is supposed to be positioned, after the affine transformation, at `c_out` (e.g. the input centre should be placed at the output centre) then `c_in=T.inv*c_out+s` or `s=c_in-T.inv*c_out` (note the conventional mathematical order of the matrix product used here, matrix*vector, which is why @timday, who used the revers order, didn't need a transposition at this point in his code).

If one wants a scaling `S` first and then a rotation `R` it holds that `T=R*S` and therefore `T.inv=S.inv*R.inv` (note the reversed order). For example, if one wants to make the image double as wide in the columns direction ('x'), then `S=diag((1, 2))`, hence `S.inv=diag((1, 0.5))`.

```
src = scipy.misc.lena()
c_in = 0.5 * array(src.shape)
dest_shape = (512, 1028)
c_out = 0.5 * array(dest_shape)
for i in xrange(0, 7):
    a = i * 15.0 * pi / 180.0
    rot = array([[cos(a), -sin(a)], [sin(a), cos(a)]])
    invRot = rot.T
    invScale = diag((1.0, 0.5))
    invTransform = dot(invScale, invRot)
    offset = c_in - dot(invTransform, c_out)
    dest = scipy.ndimage.interpolation.affine_transform(
        src, invTransform, order=2, offset=offset, output_shape=dest_shape, cval=0.0, output=float32
    )
    subplot(1, 7, i + 1);axis('off');imshow(dest, cmap=cm.gray)
show()
```

[image: Lena: first stretched, then rotated]

If the image is to be first rotated, then stretched, the order of the dot product needs to be reversed:

```
invTransform = dot(invRot, invScale)
```

[image: Lena: first rotated, then stretched]