# Transforming and Resampling a 3D volume with numpy/scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, geometry-shader, ndimage

**UPDATE:**

**I created a well documented ipython notebook.
If you just want the code, look at the first answer.**

**Question**

I've got a 40x40x40 volume of greyscale values.
This needs to be rotated/shifted/sheared.

Here is a useful collection of homogeneous transformations: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/transformations.py.html

I need to treat every voxel in my volume like a pair of (position vector, value).
Then I would transform the position and sample new values for each coordinate from the set of transformed vectors.

The sampling seems rather difficult, and I was glad to find this:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.affine_transform.html#scipy.ndimage.affine_transform

> The given matrix and offset are used to find for each point in the
>   output the corresponding coordinates in the input by an affine
>   transformation. The value of the input at those coordinates is
>   determined by spline interpolation of the requested order. Points
>   outside the boundaries of the input are filled according to the given
>   mode.

Sounds perfect.

But the usage is very tricky. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161175/how-can-i-use-scipy-ndimage-interpolation-affine-transform-to-rotate-an-image-ab) someone is using that code for rotating an image.
His rotation matrix is 2x2, so that's not in homogenous coordinates.
I tried passing a translation matrix in homogenous coordinates (2D) to the function:

```
dim =10
arr=np.zeros((dim,dim))
arr[0,0]=1
mat=np.array([[1,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
out3=scipy.ndimage.affine_transform(arr,mat)
print("out3: ",out3)
```

Which produces an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/212590884/PycharmProjects/3DAugmentation/main.py", line 32, in <module>
    out3=scipy.ndimage.affine_transform(arr,mat)
  File "C:\Users\212590884\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\ndimage\interpolation.py", line 417, in affine_transform
    raise RuntimeError('affine matrix has wrong number of rows')
RuntimeError: affine matrix has wrong number of rows
```

Apparently this doesn't work with homogeneous coordinates.
How can I use this to shift the data?

And this was just in 2D, in 3D I can't even rotate the volume:

```
dim =10
arr=np.zeros((dim,dim,dim))
arr[0,0]=1

angle=10/180*np.pi
c=np.cos(angle)
s=np.sin(angle)
mat=np.array([[c,-s,0,0],[s,c,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]])
out3=scipy.ndimage.affine_transform(arr,mat)
print("out3: ",out3)
```

The error message is the same: `affine matrix has wrong number of rows`

Is it possible to use this method to transform my volume ?

I found a collection of helper methods, they offer shift and rotate but not shear:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/ndimage.html

But I would prefer to use a custom transformation matrix.

Comment: Note that since 1.0, `affine_transform` does support homogeneous coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found another option: [map_coordinates](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates.html#scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates)

With numpy it is possible to generate a meshgrid of coordinates, then reshape/stack them to form position vectors. These vectors are transformed and converted back into the meshgrid coordinate format. Finally with `map_coordinates` the sampling problem is solved.

I think that this is a common problem and have created an ipython notebook which explains everything step by step:

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/lhk/f05ee20b5a826e4c8b9bb3e528348688

There is still one problem: The order of the coordinates is strange. You need to reorder the meshgrids in an unintuitive way. Could be a bug in my code.

Please be aware that this reordering of coordinates influences the axes of the transformations.
If you want to rotate something around the x axis, the corresponding vector is not (1,0,0) but (0,1,0), it's really strange.

But it works, and I think the principle is clear.

Comment: I think that the strange behavior is due to the (r,c,z) convention which is (y, x, z), so, the corresponding vector to rotate over the x coordinates is (0, 1, 0)

Comment: What is the (r,c,z) convention. Where does it come from? @Ariel

Comment: It stands for r=row, c=col and the other dimensions, however, the spatial x, y corresponds to  x=col and y=row. Which is similar to Cartesian (‘xy’, default) or matrix (‘ij’) indexing of output in numpy meshgrid